# Calculate googolplex binary from left to right

Tags: javascript, php, c++, c, numbers

How to calculator [googolplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googolplex) (10^(10^100)) the leading N (Ex: 100) binary digits from the left ?

I know how to calculate a binary from the right to left, but this may take hundreds of years ([Reference](http://www.fpx.de/fp/Fun/Googolplex/)) to run...

Comment: According to the link: `...Carl Sagan estimated that writing a googolplex in standard form (i.e., "10,000,000,000...") would be physically impossible, since doing so would require more space than is available in the known universe`.

Comment: But if I just want to calculate the first 100 binary digits, could it possible ?

Comment: I don't understand what `calculate the first N binary digits` means.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I mean the left side of it, Ex: 1000dec = 1111101000b, the first 6 binary digits is "111110", may be I should use "leading" =)

Answer (score 2):

Don't have an answer, but have a suggestion for further analysis.

if you want it in binary, then you want the bits starting in the Nth bit, where N=X+1 where X is described as follows:

2^X = 10^(10^100)
take log(b=10) =>

X = 10^100 / log(2) ==> ~ 3.3 E 100

Still not sure how to reduce it from there, but maybe playing with logarithm identities might be interesting.  If you can compute X, maybe you can come up with a long division algorithm, though the running time argument on your reference makes me imagine the runtime for computing this could be the same. I.e. see you in ~600 years.

Another idea might be to investigate how numeric coprocessors create iEEE mantissas in binary.

Maybe there is an algorithm there you can leverage for something like this.

Just guessing though

Answer (score 2):

So some basic math helps to outline the approach.  I'll emphasize some highlights:

- You want to compute the left digits accurately, in binary.
- Digits, mathematically, are invariant with respect to multiplication/division by the base
- Powers are equivalent to multiplication in log space
- Multiplication/division by the base is equivalent to adding whole numbers in log space

BitBlitz has the right idea--you can use logarithms to solve this.  In particular, take the logarithm of 10 in base 2, multiply that by 10^100, and ignore everything to the left of the (base 2) decimal place.  To give you an idea, 10^100 is obviously 100 digits; using the 1K=2^10=10^3 approximation, that makes about 100/3 K or 33K, times 10 which is about 330 bits of shifting the log left to get past all of those bits you don't care about.  Once you've flipped through that and start hitting the binary "decimals", you'll be computing the logarithms of the digits--left to right.  Gather a huge chunk of such digits, perform the inverse log of it, and your resulting binary digits will match what you want to get.

You're definitely going to need a bignum library for this task; long double just isn't going to cut it.  But it should be reasonably possible using this approach to gather a reasonable number of leftmost digits.